# How another UIView will appear when button is clicked

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have one `UIViewController` in that I have another `UIView`. What I want to do is when a button is pressed that `UIView` should appear swiping the main `UIViewController`.

I have tried:

```
[self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(-280.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 568.0f)];
[self.view addSubview:view_secondScreen];
```

It moves the entire `UIViewController` along the the sub view. Can any one guide me how would make the second view appear? I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do sounds like the standard pushViewController method of UINavigationController.

What you want to do is

```
[self pushViewController:viewControllerSecondScreen animated:YES];
```

But for that to work you need to have your second UIView wrapped in an UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple animation to left slide animation.

```
-(void)addLeftSlideAnimationForButton:(UIView*)yourView
{      
    CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    moveAnimation.duration = 0.02;
    moveAnimation.repeatCount=0;
    moveAnimation.autoreverses=NO;
    moveAnimation.fromValue= [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
    moveAnimation.toValue=[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(-280.0f, 0.0)];
    [yourView.layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:@"animatePosition"];
}
```

and remove animation by call this method.

```
-(void)removeLeftSlideAnimationForButton:(UIView*)yourView
{
    [yourView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"animatePosition"];
}
```

Call above method by..

```
//[self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(-280.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 568.0f)]; // comment this line
[self.view addSubview:view_secondScreen];
[self addLeftSlideAnimationForButton:view_secondScreen]
```

Comment: It does not slide the main UIViewController to right. I want it to slide to right the the UIView should appear.

Comment: No No. It won't slide main view, it just slide the subview which you've added to main view.

Comment: so how can i slide the main view??

Comment: I didn't get you. If you slide main view, what will be in background? It will be blank view after sliding? Is it ok for you?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of possible ways to do if you want to show different UI Components in two different UIView in the same UIViewController.

1. you can use UISegmentedControl
2. As you have implemented having different UIButton and showing / removing the UIView from UIViewController.

You need to have 2 different XIB file for the two different UIViews and on selecting a button add that particular UIView as a subview of UIViewController and remove earlier UIView from the superview.

I prefer doing this using UISegmentedControl.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you guide how can i use UISegmentedControl??

Comment: In the header file declare 

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;

In .m file you can implement method

- (IBAction)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)sender


You can check the link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html from Apple for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two ways through which you can add a view on a parent view
1- You can add as a subview as you are already doing, if this is the case then you must have to animate the second view while adding it on your view.
2- This one is preferable if you want to go on a next activity, means you can add a navigation controller in appdelegate and in its rootviewcontroller property you can set your view.
Then while you want to go to second view,you can push your second view on first view.
So tell me what kind of option you want in your app?

Comment: I dont want to add another ViewController, what i want is that main view should shift to right and the subView should appear as it happens in the side menu.

Comment: Ok then you have to just add some point in mainview's x coordinates and then add your second view as subview and you have to just apply simple animation during this process